# How do I add separate transparent images on an object?

Tags: materials, uv, node-editor, shaders, uv-image-editor

I'm a beginner on blender and I'm still trying my best to understand nodes, UV editing and basically everything texture related. I am trying to make a story dice which means I am trying to add transparent images to each side of the dice. I know how to do the shrink-wrap method but am trying to learn the proper way of adding materials to an object. I have a feeling it will probably be quite an obvious process but I have been trying at this for hours and am getting sort of desperate..
[image]

[image]
From the images you can see my attempts at trying to use mix nodes so I can have my transparent images show through the base color, but I cant seem to get more than 1 different image type per face, they either are all the same image or simply don't show. I hope this makes sense and I GREATLY appreciate any help that comes my way! (also why do i have so many materials, how do i delete them!?)
[image]

Comment: https://youtu.be/TMPjKVgTfYs

Comment: @Emir This didnt help my problem, but thank you anyway

Comment: Hello :). In this case, it'd be easier to have all images part of one image texture. Then you just rearrange the UV map.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, it'd be easier to have all the symbols inside one image texture.
Then you just rearrange the UV map.

[image]